# How to fix scroll positioning problem in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have `setOrder` functionally in my app, when the user choose "By Title" for example, It will make a query to the local database, and will return the list ordered by title.

The functionally works fine, and when the I click  `setOrder` it should take me to the top of sorted list.

When I in the bottom of the list this is working as expected, but if I'm in the top of the list and click  `setOrder`, It's just "follows" after the previous first item in the list.

**What I think the problem is?**

When the first item is in the view, It's still hold refference to the this item hence it will "follow" this item to his new position.

I tried several things in order to solve the problem, none of then worked.

The code:

**I call this function when user choose order**

```
        onMovieFilter()
```

In this function I make the local db call and call to `resetRecycler()`

```
private fun resetRecycler() {
    movies_recycler_view.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
}
```

**BTW** I'm still getting this behavior even if I'm not calling

```
movies_recycler_view.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
```

**Adapter Code**

```
class MoviesRecyclerViewAdapter() :
    ListAdapter<Movie, MoviesRecyclerViewAdapter.MoviesViewHolder>(
        DiffUtilCallBack()
    ) {

    private var listRef: List<Movie> = ArrayList()
    


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MoviesViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.movie_item, parent, false)
        return MoviesViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MoviesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item)
    }
    

    class MoviesViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private var movieImage = itemView.movie_image
        private var movieTitleText = itemView.movie_title_text




        fun bind(item: Movie?) {
            item?.let { movie ->
                movieTitleText.text = movie.title

                val currentUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400${movie.posterPath}"

                Glide.with(itemView.context)
                    .load(currentUrl)
                    .apply(RequestOptions.overrideOf(400, 600))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .into(movieImage)
            }
        }
        

    }

}



class DiffUtilCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Movie>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Movie, newItem: Movie): Boolean {
        return oldItem.title == newItem.title
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Movie, newItem: Movie): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

Comment: you can `movies_recycler_view.smoothScrollToPosition(0)` after the adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() has been called.

Comment: Do you mean that the list doesn't move to the top? Do you use `DiffUtils` in the adapter?

Comment: @aminography Yes I'm using DiffIutils. Basically when I in the bottom of the list It does return to the top, in other situation It's just randomly go to some position

Comment: So share the adapter source code please.

Comment: @aminography  I updated the questions with the code